Using fluentbit yaml configuration with helm chart in Kubernetes
I have started using fluentbit in my K8s cluster, and I am quite happy with it. Now, I need to utilize the processors functionality (https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/processors/opentelemetry-envelope), which is unfortunately not available in the classic config mode.
I am using Helm and configuring fluent bit using values. It seems that Helm only supports the classic configuration mode. Am I missing something? Does anybody deploy fluent bit in K8s using Helm with the YAML configuration?
I would appreciate your help as I have not found documentation about that yet.
Thanks,
Peter

You are right that the Fluent Bit Helm chart only supports the classic (TOML) configuration out of the box. However, with a bit of fiddling, you should be able to supply Yaml configuration to it.
Here's the values file I used to run the Fluent Bit Helm chart v0.47.7 with Yaml configuration:
args:
  - --workdir=/fluent-bit/etc/
  - --config=/fluent-bit/etc/conf/fluent-bit.yaml
config:
  extraFiles:
    fluent-bit.yaml: |
      pipeline:
        filters:
          - name: kubernetes
            match: kube.*
        inputs:
          - name: tail
            path: /var/log/containers/*.log
            multiline.parser:
              - docker
              - cri
            tag: kube.*
        outputs:
          - name: es
            match: kube.*
            host: my-elasticsearch
      service:
        http_server: on

Note that I have used the args property to tell Fluent Bit to read configuration from fluent-bit.yaml file instead of the default fluent-bit.conf file, and then I supplied the fluent-bit.yaml file via the config.extraFiles property. You should modify the details of the configuration to your liking.
